# In Mui Datatable The data is properly fetched and properly mapped. but not showing in the ui when i am tring to access the next page's data

Tags: reactjs, async-await, dataprovider, mui-datatable

`//This is the main code
import { TextInput, useListContext, CreateBase, Form, Toolbar, SaveButton, DateTimeInput, useRedirect } from 'react-admin';
import { Scrollbars } from 'react-custom-scrollbars';
import { Box, Grid } from '@mui/material';
import { useState } from 'react';
import SubmitIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExitToApp';
import MUIDataTable from 'mui-datatables';
import '../App.css'
import ReconDataprovider from '../Dataprovider/ReconDataprovider';
// import { isResourseHasAccess } from "../../Utils/CommonUtil";

```
const ResultComponent = ({ data,onRowClick ,setApiData,endToEndId,fromDateTimeStamp,toDateTimeStamp}) => {
    let rows = [];
    rows =(data.transactionSummary==undefined)?data.data.transactionSummary.map((transaction, index) => ({
        id: index,
        endToEndId: transaction.endToEndId,
        debtorAccountNo: transaction.details.debtorAccountNo,
        creditorAccountNo: transaction.details.creditorAccountNo,
        creditorProxy: transaction.details.creditorProxy,
        transactionAmount: transaction.details.transactionAmount,
        transactionTimeStamp:transaction.details.transactionTimeStamp,
        currencyCode: transaction.details.currencyCode,
        paymentType: transaction.details.paymentType,
        statusCode: transaction.details.statusCode ,
        reasonDescription: transaction.details.reasonDescription
    })):
    data.transactionSummary.map((transaction, index) => ({
        id: index,
        endToEndId: transaction.endToEndId,
        debtorAccountNo: transaction.details.debtorAccountNo,
        creditorAccountNo: transaction.details.creditorAccountNo,
        creditorProxy: transaction.details.creditorProxy,
        transactionAmount: transaction.details.transactionAmount,
        transactionTimeStamp:transaction.details.transactionTimeStamp,
        currencyCode: transaction.details.currencyCode,
        paymentType: transaction.details.paymentType,
        statusCode: transaction.details.statusCode ,
        reasonDescription: transaction.details.reasonDescription
    }))
    ;
    const customStyles = {
        container: {
            // background: "#000000",
            whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
            fontWeight: '10px',
            flexDirection:'column'
            // backgroundColor:"#000000"
            // Add custom styles for the table container
            
        },
        headCells: {
            whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
            flexDirection:'column'
            // Add other custom styles for header cells here
        },
    };

    const columns = [
        { name: 'endToEndId', label:<b>      End To End Id</b> },
        { name: 'debtorAccountNo', label: <b>Debtor Account No</b> },
        { name: 'creditorAccountNo', label: <b>Creditor Account No</b> },
        { name: 'creditorProxy', label: <b>Creditor  Proxy</b> },
        { name: 'transactionAmount', label: <b>Transaction  Amount</b> },
        { name: 'transactionTimeStamp', label: <b>Transaction  Date</b> },
        { name: 'currencyCode', label: <b>Currency  Code</b> },
        { name: 'statusCode', label: <b>Status  Code</b> },
        { name: 'reasonDescription', label: <b>Reason  Description</b> }
    ];
    const fetchData = async (page, rowsPerPage) => {
        try {
        // Make your API call here using the new page and rowsPerPage values
        // For example, if you are using react-admin dataProvider
        const updatedData = await ReconDataprovider.create(
            'payment-summary', // replace with your resource name
            { pagination: { page:page+1, perPage: rowsPerPage } ,data:{endToEndId,fromDateTimeStamp,toDateTimeStamp}}
        );
    
        // Update the state or perform any action with the fetched data
        setApiData(updatedData);
        } catch (error) {
        // Handle error
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        }
    };
    const options = {
        selectableRows: false,
        setTableProps: () => ({
        style: customStyles.container,
        }),
        customHeadRender: (columnMeta) => (
        <th style={customStyles.headCells}>{columns[columnMeta.colIndex].label}</th>
        ),
        onRowClick: (rowData) => {
        const selectedEndToEndId = rowData[columns.findIndex((col) => col.name === 'endToEndId')];
        onRowClick(selectedEndToEndId);
        },
        print:false,
        search: false,
        viewColumns: false,
        pagination: true,  // Enable pagination
        rowsPerPageOptions: [5,10, 20, 50,100],  // Define the available rows per page options
        count:(data.page==undefined)?data.data.page.totalElements:data.page.totalElements,
        onTableChange: (action, tableState) => {
            // Check if the action is a change in pagination or rows per page
            if (action === 'changePage' || action === 'changeRowsPerPage') {
            const { page, rowsPerPage } = tableState;
    
            // Fetch data based on the new page and rowsPerPage
            fetchData(page, rowsPerPage);
            }
        }
    };
    
    return (
        <div className='MUIDataTableHeadCell'>
        <MUIDataTable data={rows} columns={columns} options={options} />
        </div>
    );
    };

export const PostReconFilterForm = ({onRowClickProp, ...props }) => {
    const {
        displayedFilters,
        filterValues,
        setFilters,
        hideFilter
    } = useListContext();
    const formatDateToISOString = (date) => {
        return date.toISOString();
    };
    const refresh = () => {
        window.location.reload();
    };

    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
    const [apiData, setApiData] = useState();
    const handleButtonClick = () => {
        setIsOpen(true);
    };
    const handledialogClose1 = () => {
        setIsOpen(false);
    };
    const [endToEndId, setEndToEndId] = useState(undefined);
    const handleChangeEndToEndId = (e) => {
        setEndToEndId(e.target.value);
    }
    const [fromDateTimeStamp, setFromDateTimeStamp] = useState('');
    const [toDateTimeStamp, setToDateTimeStamp] = useState('');
    const handleChageStartDate = (e) => {
        const isoDateTime = new Date(e.target.value).toISOString();
        setFromDateTimeStamp(isoDateTime);
    }
    
    const handleChageEndDate = (e) => {
        const isoDateTime = new Date(e.target.value).toISOString();
        setToDateTimeStamp(isoDateTime);
    }
    
    const validateCurrentDatetime = (value) => {
        const userDatetime = new Date(value);
        const currentDatetime = new Date();
    
        if (currentDatetime < userDatetime) {
        return 'Entered datetime must be greater than the current datetime.';
        }
    
        // Return undefined if validation passes
        return undefined;
    };
    //   const validateEndToEndId = () =>{
    //     if(endToEndId.length>35){
    //         return 'Size must be in between 1 to 35';
    //     }
    //     return true;
    //   }
    // const redirect = useRedirect();
    const onRowClick = (selectedEndToEndId) => {
        console.log("Selected End To End Id:", selectedEndToEndId);
        localStorage.setItem('selectedEndToEndId', selectedEndToEndId);
        const url = `${window.location.origin}/portal-external/#/reconciliations`
        // Redirect to the 'com' resource with the selected endToEndId
        window.open(url,'_blank');
        // redirect(`/com`,'_blank');
    }
    const datetimeValueFromDataSource = new Date();
    const formattedDatetime = formatDateToISOString(datetimeValueFromDataSource);
    const handleDefaultDateChange = () => {
        if(fromDateTimeStamp.length>0 && toDateTimeStamp.length>0){
            if (fromDateTimeStamp > toDateTimeStamp) {
                return 'End date Must be grater than the Start Date';
            } 
        }
    }
    return (
        <CreateBase>
            <Form >
                <Box display="flex" alignItems="flex-end" marginTop='3%' >
                    <Grid container >
                        <Grid item={true} xs={12} sm={3} md={3} lg={3} xl={3} >
                            <TextInput
                                helperText={false}
                                source="endToEndId"
                                value={endToEndId}
                                label="End To End Id"
                                onChange={handleChangeEndToEndId}
                                variant="standard"
                                style={{ width: "85%" }}
                            /></Grid>
                        <Grid item={true} xs={12} sm={3} md={3} lg={3} xl={3} >
                            <DateTimeInput
                                helperText={false}
                                source="fromDateTimeStamp"
                                label="Start Date"
                                variant="standard"
                                onChange={handleChageStartDate}
                                validate={[validateCurrentDatetime,handleDefaultDateChange]}
                                // value={formattedDatetime}
                                style={{ width: "85%" }}
                            /></Grid>
                        <Grid item={true} xs={12} sm={3} md={3} lg={3} xl={3}>
                            <DateTimeInput
                                helperText={false}
                                source="toDateTimeStamp"
                                onChange={handleChageEndDate}
                                label="End Date"
                                style={{ width: "85%" }}
                                variant="standard"
                                // value={formattedDatetime}
                                validate={[validateCurrentDatetime,handleDefaultDateChange]}
                            /></Grid>
                        <Grid item={true} xs={12} sm={3} md={3} lg={3} xl={4}>
                            <Toolbar {...props} sx={{ display: 'flex', backgroundColor: "#ffffff", justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                                <SaveButton
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    redirect="list"
                                    submitOnEnter={true}
                                    label="Submit"
                                    icon={<SubmitIcon />}
                                    // onClick={handleButtonClick}
                                    mutationOptions={{
                                        onSuccess: (value) => {
                                            setApiData(value);
                                            handleButtonClick();
                                        },
                                    }}
                                    type='button'
                                />
                            </Toolbar></Grid>
                    </Grid>

                </Box>

            </Form>
            <Scrollbars style={{ height: '85%' }} className='MuiTableCell'>
                <Box marginTop='4%' >
                    {isOpen &&
                        <ResultComponent data={apiData} onRowClick={onRowClick} setApiData={setApiData} endToEndId={endToEndId} fromDateTimeStamp={fromDateTimeStamp} toDateTimeStamp={toDateTimeStamp}/>}
                </Box>
            </Scrollbars>
        </CreateBase>
    );
};
```

//This is data provider.
import { rsDeHttpClient } from "./MainDataprovider";

```
const recon_list = '/insurance/v1/payment-summary';
export default {
    create: (resource, params) =>{
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            rsDeHttpClient(`${recon_list}`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "fromDateTimeStamp":params.data.fromDateTimeStamp,
                "toDateTimeStamp": params.data.toDateTimeStamp,
                "endToEndId":params.data.endToEndId  ,
                "limit":(params.pagination==undefined)?10:params.pagination.perPage,
                "offset":(params.pagination==undefined)?1:params.pagination.page
            }),
        })
        .then(response=>response.json)
        .then(json => {
            const data = {id:1, ...json };
            resolve({ data });
          })
        .catch(error => {
          reject(error);
        });
      });
    },
};`your text`
```

/* The code is working fine when for the first time the data is loading . but when i am changing it to next page I am not able to see the data in the next page but the the data is fetched correctly from the backend when i am changing the page.*/ `

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).